# CSRF token mismatch when laravel used in multiple system

Tags: php, laravel, csrf-token

I'm trying to migrate laravel from version 5.2 to 6.0 , but i have different folder for different version in same local wamp server . I'm using same database file both version . But i'm always getting csrf token mismatch and page expired . Please give me some good solutions for this.

Comment: have you cleared your cookies?

Comment: open both url in different browser ( one in chrome and other on firefox ), let us know your observation.

Comment: So do you have different vhosts for the different versions or do you just use "localhost" for all those projects? I'd advice setting up vhosts with different domain names (i.e. "la52.local", "la56.local" etc.) for every project you have. Or use `php artisan serve` in the different folders

Comment: I'm using different vhost for each version

Comment: Using same DB file for both versions

Comment: Which session driver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes from the CSRF token verification which fails. So either you're not posting one or you're posting an incorrect one.

Use `{{ csrf_field() }}` in your form

**OR**

Add Your Route URL into the `Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` file.

Example Like this. If your ajax route `Route::post('searchsubmit','User\UserController@ViewSearchList')->name('searchsubmit');`

**Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php**

```
protected $except = [
       'searchsubmit',
    ];
```

In Your Case You need to add `login` like this

```
protected $except = [
           'login',
        ];
```

Comment: `cache:clear` is for flushing your cache store, it has nothing to do with the configuration or anything like that

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` also runs `php artisan config:clear`. And caching config on DEV systems is not advised

Comment: this is a good solution but i dont recommend that. you should put csrf token for all your forms. maybe php clear all config and caches help you. you can also check @csrf instead of csrf_token()

Comment: @kerbholz finally someone else who gets that point about not needing it cached on development :) drives me crazy everytime someone says to cache it

Comment: i used all above command , my problems is when another guys use same laravel project from my system in his system from networks this problems occur.

Comment: @aliFalahati I'm using csrf_token in all forms , for repeatation of code i'm using csrf_token in master blade page .